# Mapping postgres enum to java string

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, enums

I am new to Spring boot and Postgres and was wondering how to map from a Postgres enum to a Java string. For example, say I have the following type in Postgres:

```
CREATE TYPE mood AS ENUM ('sad', 'ok', 'happy');
```

And the following in my java code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "information")
public class Information {

   @NotNull
   private String mood;
}
```

I’ve seen things about how to map from Postgres enums to Java enums, but I could not find anything about mapping from Postgres enums to Java strings. Is there anything special I need to do?

EDIT: I need to keep the type as a String in Java based on other requirements. I do **not** want to create an enum in Java

Comment: And what is the problem with your example? Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, im getting the following: "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"

Answer (score 0):

In java you can create an enum:

```
 public enum Mod {

  SAD("sad"),OK("ok"),HAPPY("happy");
  private String desc;
  public Mod(String desc) }
    this.desc = desc; }
  @Override public String toString() {
  return desc;}
 }
```

You can get String by calling

```
 Mod.OK.toString()
```

Comment: I need to keep the type as a string in java based on other requirements (I made an edit to my original post)